# Looking for a way to stop a process while calling a function without return

Tags: php, zend-framework, coding-style, phpmd

I have developped an habit of using a return to stop a code sequence from executing, even if the return is used on a function that  returns nothing

```
$form = $this->getForm('activity');    
$this->view->form = $form;
return $this->render('create'); // Like this
```

In Zend Framework it stop the execution of the current action and renders the view which name is the parameter of the function `$this->render()`.

I have recently ran [PHPMD](http://phpmd.org/) on my code and all of those statements gets flagged as `Void function result used`

I was wondering, how bad is this habit and what would be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only point I see is that `$this->render('create')` returns **void** which should not be returned again.

If the action does not require any return value (Zend Framework 1), then you should place your `return` on a separate line without any return value.

```
$form = $this->getForm('activity');    
$this->view->form = $form;
$this->render('create'); // Like this
return;
```

This is common syntax in Zend Framework at least for `forward`. You will also often see it for `redirect`, but this one already has an exit-statement within the Zend code. According to the [ZF1 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.controller.action.html) the intention of forward is to execute the current action and then also execute a second action. But in their code example, they also use `return $this->_forward()`. On my job however, I learnt to put the `return` onto a new line to make clear that nothing is returned.

As an alternative, you can of course use `if else` blocks. However, in my opinion they are not always clearer (and I am not a fan of these strict Java rules).

```
if ($something) {
    $this->_forward();
} else {
    // do other code
}
```

Comment: using `return;` gives you a `missing return argument` which is not really better (and yes its Zend Framework 1)

Comment: Quick question. Does return; return null?

Comment: @Ignas: Tested and yes it does.